# Вывести содержимое массива улиткой в данном порядке (может быть четным и нечетным)

Tags: c++, c

Массив может быть четным и нечетным, но всегда квадратным, вывести необходимо в данном порядке, как изображено на изображении))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Массив всегда квадратный, размер от 0 до 7**

Comment: А сколько за это отвалят?) Решу за 100 грн!)

Comment: Ну а у меня время дороже! Нет времени тут за 10 репутации задачки для новичков решать.

Comment: чтовы сделали для решения вопроса? что у вас не получается реализовать?

Comment: Для начала вам нужно предоставить код, где вы пытались решить задачу и где-то что-то не получается. Потом составте вопрос, чтобы соответствовал [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) правилам, а не то продолжат выражать сарказм и минусовать, а потом закроют.

Answer (score -1):

Я уже сделал такую матрицу. Посмотрите мой код по ссылке и переделайте под себя. Займёт пару часов, зато Вы начнёте лучше понимать C++.
https://code.sololearn.com/ctQlnmwTAE4w/#cpp
https://code.sololearn.com/chCFI443yhKn/#cpp
Специально скинул 2 кода, ибо решал 2-мя способами: изнутри и снаружи.